# Create DBIx ResultSet using column aliases

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I have started to use DBIx::Class and I really like it for the most part but what is really starting to annoy me is the column alias does not seem to work fully.

Eg. Suppose I have this table definition:

```
#TestClass.pm

use strict;
use warnings;

package Database::Schema::Result::TestClass;

use base qw/DBIx::Class::Core/;

__PACKAGE__->table("TEST_TABLE");
__PACKAGE__->add_column("ID")
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(NAME => {accessor => "name"},
                         VALUE => {accessor => "value"}
                         );
```

And then I try to create a new row as follows:

```
 $schema->resultset("TestClass")->create(name => "test", value => "value");
```

The above will say: 
DBIx::Class::ResultSet::create(): No such column name on Database::Schema::Result::TestClass

However the following works fine:

```
 $schema->resultset("TestClass")->create(NAME => "test", VALUE => "value");
```

If later on I have TestClass object and try to access its columns as such:

```
 $object->NAME;
```

I get Can't locate object method "NAME" via package "Database::Schema::Result::TestClass"

but this is ok:

```
 $object->name
```

I would expect to be able to create the object using the accessor I provided the column and for creation of the object and accessing the columns to be consistent but this does not seem to be the case. Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: "does not work" is not a useful error description, please paste the actual error message!

Comment: You're telling add_columns `NAME` and `VALUE` but you're telling create `name` and `value`.  SQL may be case insensitive but DBIx::Class probably isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your dilemma lies in [part 3 of the *DBIx::Class Tutorial*](http://search.cpan.org/~jrobinson/DBIx-Class-Tutorial-0.0001/lib/DBIx/Class/Tutorial/Part3.pod#Changing_the_standard_accessors). Also,  the [manual page for the `add_columns` method of `DBIx::Class::ResultSource` class](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class-0.08250/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSource.pm#add_columns) states that: *Use this* (the `accessor` property) *to set the name of the accessor method for this column. If unset, the name of the column will be used.*

Basically what you did was to define a column `NAME` and create an accessor for it `name`